# Performing function on object and then manipulating the object in Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm struggling with a little bit of ramda logic, which I feel like I've almost got a grasp on, but my brain is just not working properly today.

I have an object:

```
const thing = {
  'name': 'thing',
  'value': 1000.0987654321,
  'valueAsString': "1000.0987654321",
  'otherThings': { 'blah': 'blah' },
}
```

I want to extract 'name' and 'value' from thing, but I want to round the value before returning my new object.

I know that to extract name and value I can just use pick: `R.pick(['name', 'value'])` and to perform my rounding function, I can take an existing rounding function:

```
const roundTo9Dp = (n) => Number((n).toFixed(9))
```

and apply this to my object like this: `R.compose(roundTo9Dp, R.prop('value'))`

These two operations work independently:

```
const picker = R.pick(['name', 'value'])
picker(thing) // => {"name": "thing", "value": 1000.0987654321}

const rounded = R.compose(roundTo9Dp, R.prop('value'))
rounded(thing) // => 1000.098765432
```

It's when I join them together, I'm struggling. It's like they're operating on 'thing' at different levels, and I'm just struggling to unpick them.

```
R.compose(picker, R.assoc('value', rounded))(thing) // Incorrect
picker(R.compose(R.assoc('value'), rounded)(thing)(thing)) // works, but is hideous
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few ways you could do this with Ramda.  Here are a few:

```js
const roundTo9Dp = (n) => Number((n).toFixed(9))

const foo1 = applySpec({
  name: prop('name'),
  value: compose(roundTo9Dp, prop('value'))
})

const foo2 = pipe(
  pick (['name', 'value']),
  over (lensProp ('value'), roundTo9Dp)
)

const rounded = R.compose(roundTo9Dp, R.prop('value'))
const foo3 = pipe(
  pick (['name', 'value']),
  chain(assoc('value'), rounded)
)

const foo4 = pipe(
  props (['name', 'value']),
  zipWith (call, [identity, roundTo9Dp]),
  zipObj (['name', 'value'])
)

const thing = {name: 'thing', value: 1000.0987654321, valueAsString: "1000.0987654321", otherThings: {blah: 'blah'}}

console .log ('foo1:', foo1 (thing))
console .log ('foo2:', foo2 (thing))
console .log ('foo3:', foo3 (thing))
console .log ('foo4:', foo4 (thing))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {applySpec, prop, compose, pipe, pick, over, lensProp, chain, assoc, props, zipWith, call, identity, zipObj} = R </script>
```

And we could come up with many more if we tried.  `foo3` is probably closest to what you were struggling with.  [`chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) when applied to functions works like `chain (f, g) (x) //=> f (g (x)) (x)`, which would avoid the ugly `(thing) (thing)` in your version.  This version might teach you some about the world of [FantasyLand](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain) typeclasses.  `foo1` uses one of Ramda's more convenient object manipulation functions, [`applySpec`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#applySpec).  `foo2` uses [`lensProp`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensProp) and [`over`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#over), which can lead you into the fascinating world of lenses.  And `foo4`, while probably not recommended, shows off [`zipWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith) and [`zipObj`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipObj), functions used to combine lists.

But unless this is about *learning* Ramda, I would suggest none of these, as this is simple enough to do without any library in modern JS:

```js
const foo = ({name, value}) => 
  ({name, value: roundTo9Dp(value)})
```

I'm one of the founders of Ramda, and I remain a big fan.  But I see it as a library to be used when it makes code cleaner and more maintainable.  Here, the simplest version doesn't need it.

Comment: Thank-you for this excellent answer, it's given me a lot of go away, experiment with and learn from.

Comment: The original question was a deliberate simplification of the problem I'm attempting to solve, but I also share your enthusiasm for picking a pragmatic solution that favours cleaner and more maintainable code, so I will be sure to remind myself of that when it comes to actually committing to my VCS, especially since the original code I wrote looks very similar to the non-ramda solution.

Comment: @purpletonic: I'd suggest that if you have a number of properties to modify, then you might want to pipe together multiple `lens` calls similar to the one above, `over (lensProp ('value'), roundTo9Dp)`.  Or investigate `evolve`.  But either of those only work if the output property has the same name as the input one and it depends only on that input value.  If you have more complex scenarios, then `applySpec` is slightly less convenient, but much more powerful.